# Selecting records matching ONLY/AND criteria on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to select persons that are *ONLY* Asian *AND* White. For example in my table below, the only person I would like to retrieve records for is PersonId 1 and 2 (Desired Result).

Table:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can get the result.

Using a HAVING clause with an aggregate function:

```
select personid, race
from yourtable
where personid in 
    (select personid
     from yourtable
     group by personid
     having 
       sum(case when race = 'white' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       and sum(case when race = 'asian' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       and sum(case when race not in('asian', 'white') then 1 else 0 end) = 0);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e559/4)

Or you can use `count(distinct race)` in a having clause:

```
;with cte as
(
  select personid
  from yourtable
  where race in ('white', 'asian')
    and personid not in (select personid
                         from yourtable
                         where race not in ('white', 'asian'))
  group by personid
  having count(distinct race) = 2
)
select personid, race
from yourtable
where personid in (select personid
                   from cte);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e559/7)

Comment: Thanks! I like the second solution as this looks setup to easily plug in the values for race and count through some input parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This should do

```
select * from table where personID in (
select personID from table
group by personID having count(distinct race) = 2 and min(race) = 'Asian'
and max(race) = 'White')
```

Comment: This works but isn't using min and max restricting me to only using two races? What if I wanted to do the same query but with 3 or more races? (which is definitely my case).

Comment: @leo.t, in which case I refer you to Bluefeet's solution

Answer (score 0):

Very naive, but should work.

```
select * from yourtable t1 join yourtable t2 on t1.id = t2.id where ((t1.race = 'Asian' and t2.race = 'White') OR (t1.race = 'White' and t2.race = 'Asian')) and t1.id not in (select id from yourtable where race not in ('Asian','white'));
```